# How can I make text in UITextField all lowercase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uitextfield

I have the below query to firebase which searches for usernames.

```
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("UsernameIndex")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: username).queryEnding(atValue: username+"\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snap in
```

The issue is that if I type  upercase at any point it will not search so how can i make all leters lower case or make the text lowercase or make the query not case sensitive?

The best I have been able to do to make the text lowercase is:

```
        searchField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    searchField.autocorrectionType = .no
    searchField.spellCheckingType = .no
```

But this still allows teh user to type uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with just transferring the text to lowercase (`searchField.text.lowercased()`) and allowing the user to type in capital letters. This will stop the user from being frustrated when trying to type a capital letter.